# VB.NET Image is not displaying in Sending HTML e-mail with embedded images (Net.Mail)

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to send an email with embedded images but sadly the image is not displaying in email here is what showing in Email

[image: Click to see the Image]

And here is the code that i used

```
 Dim img1 As LinkedResource = New LinkedResource("E:\OLD\avatar\bela.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg)
            img1.ContentId = "Image1"


            e_mail.Body = "<div style=""border-style: solid; border-width: thin; border-color: gray; background-color: RGB(247, 248, 249);  margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 25%;"">
                           <p>This is the Logo<p>
                           <img src=""cid:Image1"" alt='image descddription'/>
                           </div> "
```

What do you think I'm missing here? is it wrong syntax or is it a problem with gmail itself?

Comment: Based on that code, you appear to be creating a `LinkedResource` but never adding it to the message.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i added the image in the Body using this command  `code:  <img src=""cid:Image1"" alt='image descddription'/> `

Comment: That has absolutely nothing to do with what I said. Read the words. You are creating a `LinkedResource` object in the first line of your code but at no point do you creating any association between that object and your `MailMessage`. As such, the value in the `src` attribute of the `img` tag is invalid. The message contains no resource with that ID because you never added one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly no expert on this subject but I did create an email recently with an embedded image so I'll share what I did there. I may be missing some relevant details that could enable it to be done better but you should be able to do as I did and get it to work. Note that I wrote my code in C# but I'll translate the relevant parts to VB.

I don't think that you can add linked resources directly to the message. I think that you need to create at least one `AlternateView` and add the resources to that. I created a message with an HTML view for those clients that supported it and a text view for those that don't. I created a common method to send various similarly-formatted messages. Here is what I consider the relevant parts of that for you:

```vb
Private Sub SendEmail(fromAddress As String,
                      toAddress As String,
                      subject As String,
                      body As String,
                      resourceFilePath As String)
    Using message As New MailMessage(fromAddress,
                                     toAddress,
                                     subject,
                                     body) With {.IsBodyHtml = True},
          htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body,
                                                                 Encoding.UTF8,
                                                                 MediaTypeNames.Text.Html),
          resource As New LinkedResource(resourceFilePath,
                                         MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg) With {.ContentId = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(resourceFilePath)}
        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(resource)
        message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView)

        'Send message here.
    End Using
End Sub
```

Firstly, note that all the disposable objects are created with a `using` statement, so that they are all disposed at the end.

As for the issue, note the creation of the alternate view, the creation of the linked resource, the addition of the resource to the view and then the addition of the view to the message.

In this case, I'm using the name of the file as the ID for the resource.

Comment: I try using this  
`code 
Dim imageView As New AlternateView("E:\OLD\avatar\bela.jpg",
        MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg)
            
imageView.ContentId = "uniqueId"
          
  imageView.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64

            e_mail.Body = "<img src=""cid:uniqueId"" alt='image descddription'/>"` and sadly is till not displaying image properly

Comment: @GorillaByte, please don't try to post code snippets of any length in comments. They are just too hard to read, even formatted. If it's information relevant to the question then it should be in the question. I have added the promised code to my answer.